# how to call a function only for different combination of id and product

Tags: python

I want to call function "func1" for different combination of id and product,can anyone suggest how to do that?

```
if integrated_flag != True:
    response = func1(id, product, target, Status)
```

Comment: A `for` loop comes to mind. How are `id` and `product` stored? Are they in a list, a dictionary, a database?

Comment: Whats wrong with what you have there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming response is a string and you want them concatenated (joined together)...

```
knownPairs = []

#Get a new list of Ids/Product

response = ''
for i in ListOfIds:
    for p in ListOfProducts:
        pair = (i, p)
        if not pair in knownPairs:
            response += func1(i, p, target, Status)
        else:
            knownPairs += pair
```

or on a one-at-a-time basis:

```
knownPairs = []

while(morePairsAvailable):
    #Get a new Id/Product

    response = ''
    pair = (id, product)
        if not pair in knownPairs:
            response += func1(id, product, target, Status)
        else:
            knownPairs += pair
```

Will call the function with every combination of Id and Product. As to how you get the lists of Ids/Products, that depends on your system

Comment: I don't think you meant to put the brackets there.

Comment: @basic - instead of this way,is there a way I can way I can punch in the id and prod into some hash table and check if that combination is not present in the hash table for subsequent runs?

Comment: @DSM You're right... I was using them to imply list syntax to give the OP a hint but I agree it's counter-intuitive

Comment: @user3654069 How are you planning to preserve the hash table across runs? And what do you mean by "plugging in"? typing into a console/somewhere in your code? Even better, take a step back... What are you trying to accomplish? Some sort of caching so that if it's already been calculated, you can look up the previous result or??? Your current requirement doesn't make much sense which implies you're trying to solve the wrong problem

Comment: @basic - goal is to call func1 for unique combination of id and prod,so if func1 is already ran for a combo of (id and prod) we dont want to call func1 again...hash table can be a global one so that the data is preserved across runs...

Comment: When the python interpreter exits, there is no "Global" that remains. Next time you start the script it's a fresh run with no state. If you want to preserve across runs, you need to write the output to disk or keep the process running while you get more input. Can't you just get a list of all id/product combinations to start with? Why do you only want to call it once. What's the bigger picture?

Comment: oh no..i interpreted "across runs" wrongly..no need to preserver across runs then... we cannot get list of id/product combinations and it needs to be called only once

Answer (score 0):

Having list of id + product combinations:

```
id_prod_lst = [
        [1, "a"],
        [2, "b"],
        [3, "c"],
        [2, "b"],
        [3, "c"]
        ]
```

Use set to find only unique instances. Set requires immutable items, for this we turn list to tuples:

```
uniq_id_prod_set = set(tuple(itm) for itm in id_prod_lst)
print uniq_id_prod_set
```

Having the function to call:

```
def longfunc(pr_id, product, target, stat):
    print pr_id, product, target, stat
    return
```

Finally, calll it in a loop:

```
for pr_id, product in uniq_id_prod_set:
    longfunc(pr_id, product, "T->bum", "Status")
```

The output shall be:

```
set([(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')])
for loop
1 a T->bum Status
2 b T->bum Status
3 c T->bum Status
```

Comment: the script doesnt have have the list of ids and prods handy,so,is there a way we can punch in the (id and prod) combo into some hash table and check if that combination is not present in the hastable for subsequent runs and only then call the function?